# Как подтвердить свой адрес в Google Play Console в Беларуси?

Tags: google-play, google-play-console, google-play-services, google-console

Столкнулся со следующей проблемой, буду ОЧЕНЬ признателен ща помощь. Постоянно отклоняют документы, которые могли бы подтвердить мой адрес, и я уже не знаю, что мне отправить из всего списка перечисленных документов у меня уже не осталось вариантов. Люди, которые смогли зарегистрировать и подтвердить аккаунт разработчика в Беларуси пожалуйста скажите какой документ вы предъявляли при подтверждении адреса, а то я уже не знаю, что делать.